# Unable to read data from text label and store in database

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

please guide me i am new to python. I am creating Library Management project in Add librarian section i am inserting all the required information but unable to store the data in database.
As per my thinking i am not able to read data from label below is the code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import sqlite3


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


def addentry() :

       db = sqlite3.connect("LibManagment.db")
       cur=db.cursor()
       Name = str()
       Password = str()
       Email = str()
       Address = str()
       City = str()
       Contect = int()
       cur.execute('INSERT INTO Add_lib2 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);', (Name, Password, Email, Address, City, Contect))
       print("Entry Added To Database")
       db.commit()
       showinfo( title = "Librarian Add", message = "Data inserted To table")
def viewentry() :

       db = sqlite3.connect("LibManagment.db")
       cursor=db.cursor()
       cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Add_lib2')
       for row in cursor.fetchall():
           print(row)
       db.commit()

class Myproj(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, Adminlogin, Liblogin, Adsection, Addlib):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Library Managment system", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Admin Login",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Adminlogin))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Lib Login",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Liblogin))
        button2.pack()


class Adminlogin(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        name_label = tk.Label(self, text="User ID:", font=LARGE_FONT)
        name_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        name_lable = tk.Entry(self)
        name_lable.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        pwd_label = tk.Label(self, text="Password", font=LARGE_FONT)
        pwd_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        pwd_lable = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        pwd_lable.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Login",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Adsection))
        button2.pack()


class Liblogin(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Lname_label = tk.Label(self, text="User ID:", font=LARGE_FONT)
        Lname_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        Lname_lable = tk.Entry(self)
        Lname_lable.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        Lpwd_label = tk.Label(self, text="Password", font=LARGE_FONT)
        Lpwd_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        Lpwd_lable = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        Lpwd_lable.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Login",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Adminlogin))
        button2.pack()

class Adsection(tk.Frame):


        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Add Librarian",
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Addlib))
            button1.pack()

            button2 = tk.Button(self, text="View Librarian",
                                command=viewentry)
            button2.pack()

            button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Delete Librarian",
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
            button3.pack()

            button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Logout",
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
            button4.pack()



class Addlib(tk.Frame):


        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            Libname_label = tk.Label(self, text="Name:", font=LARGE_FONT)
            Libname_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            namevar = tk.StringVar()
            Libname_lable = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=namevar)
            Name = namevar.get()
            Libname_lable.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            Libpass_label = tk.Label(self, text="Password:", font=LARGE_FONT)
            Libpass_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            pwdvar = tk.StringVar()
            Libpass_label = tk.Entry(self, show ='*', textvariable=pwdvar)
            Password = pwdvar.get()
            Libpass_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            Libemail_label = tk.Label(self, text="Email:", font=LARGE_FONT)
            Libemail_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            emailvar = tk.StringVar()
            Libemail_label = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=emailvar)
            Email = emailvar.get()
            Libemail_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            LibAddres_label = tk.Label(self, text="Address:", font=LARGE_FONT)
            LibAddres_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            addressvar = tk.StringVar()
            LibAddres_label = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=addressvar)
            Address = addressvar.get()
            LibAddres_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            Libcity_label = tk.Label(self, text="City:", font=LARGE_FONT)
            Libcity_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            cityvar = tk.StringVar()
            Libcity_label = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=cityvar)
            City = cityvar.get()
            Libcity_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            Libcontect_label = tk.Label(self, text="Contect:", font=LARGE_FONT)
            Libcontect_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            contectvar =tk.StringVar()
            Libcontect_label = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=contectvar)
            Contect = contectvar.get()
            Libcontect_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

            button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Add",
                                command=addentry)

            button1.pack()
            button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

            button4.pack()







app = Myproj()
app.mainloop()
```

I am facing problem in storing data in database which i am inserting in label filed.

Comment: Please edit your post to correct the syntax. In Python Indentation is important and currently it's a mess ;-) - Paste your code, highlight it and use `Ctrl` + `K` to indent the whole block.

Comment: You are not even trying to read the data from the label.

Comment: Thanks for your input In Addlib class i am reading the data by using get method but in think i am making some mistake in storing data in database if possible can you please suggest something so that it can work

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the widget values right after creating the widget:

```
        namevar = tk.StringVar()
        Libname_lable = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=namevar)
        Name = namevar.get()
```

At this time, the widget is still empty.

You have to read the value right before you are executing the INSERT.
(It does not help that at that place, you are overwriting everything with empty values.)

```
   Name = str()
   Password = str()
   Email = str()
   Address = str()
   City = str()
   Contect = int()
   cur.execute('INSERT INTO Add_lib2 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);', (Name, Password, Email, Address, City, Contect))
```

Comment: Thanks again for pointing My mistake. can you please let me know how can i use inside class variable namevar to store in database when i am using it i am getting Error:

ameError: name 'namevar' is not defined

Comment: You can use *class* variables inside the *class*, i.e., in any method in that class.

Comment: Thanks again for your input I have declared variable inside the class but now i am getting below error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "ank.py", line 162, in <module>
        class Addlib(tk.Frame):
       File "ank.py", line 165, in Addlib
        self.Name = tk.StringVar()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 337, in __init__
        Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
       File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 236, in __init__
   self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'`

Comment: I have declared variable in my class Addlib()

`$`class Addlib(tk.Frame):
    self.Name = tk.StringVar()
    self.password = tk.StringVar()
    self.emailvar = tk.StringVar()
    self.addressvar = tk.StringVar()
    self.cityvar = tk.StringVar()
    self.contectvar = tk.StringVar()

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Libname_label = tk.Label(self, text="Name:", font=LARGE_FONT)
        Libname_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
       # Name = tk.StringVar()
        Libname_lable = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=Name)`$`

Comment: Comments are not the proper place for large code blocks. If you have a different question about a different piece of code, ask a new question.